# Should the question ban provide more information to users? Specifically show older deleted posts

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I've stumbled across:

["You have asked 4 questions recently", but I have only asked 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367479/2191572)

and the numbers do not add up for OP.

Is there a way for OP to get more detail as to which questions are causing the ban?

I don't have question ban experience so if there is something in the UI that OP is missing then please let me know via screenshot or other.

---

From [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/2191572)

I see the **How can I find my deleted posts?** section but it suggests that it is OK to not let a user know which posts are working against them?

Comment: Not sure why this was dupe-hammered. Is it considered not beneficial to provide concrete evidence as to why a user was banned?

Comment: If you read the duplicate, you'd have the answer to that question.  That's why it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy I see that I might not have worded my question very well. Given my update, I don't think that the dupe is proper anymore.

Comment: In what way does it fail to answer your question?

Comment: @Servy Yeah, you're right.